# How do I change someones nickname to [AFK] when using this command and when they're back change it back to normal?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So what I'm trying to do is when the member uses this afk command it adds [AFK] in their nickname and when they're back it changes to the og username

```py
afkdict = {}
@client.command(name = "afk", brief = "Away From Keyboard",
                description = "I'll give you the afk status and if someone pings you before you come back, I'll tell "
                              "them that you are not available. You can add your own afk message!")
async def afk(ctx, message = "Gatau ngapain"):
    global afkdict

    if ctx.message.author in afkdict:
        afkdict.pop(ctx.message.author)
        await ctx.send('Welkom bek :-)')

    else:
        afkdict[ctx.message.author] = message
        await ctx.send("Siap bang jago")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global afkdict

    for member in message.mentions:  
        if member != message.author:  
            if member in afkdict:  
                afkmsg = afkdict[member]  
                await message.channel.send(f"{member}lagi afk. {afkmsg}")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Hi. Please edit the question and add more detail. Also, many parts of your code are not in a code block. Please edit that too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a **specific question** about your algorithm or technique. If you have no idea where to start, you need to look up a tutorial or talk to a tutor.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `member.edit(nick=nickname)`. So in your case it would be `await ctx.author.edit(nick="[AFK]")` and to remove the nickname `await ctx.author.edit(nick="")`

So the complete command would be this

```py
@client.command(name = "afk", brief = "Away From Keyboard",
                description = "I'll give you the afk status and if someone pings you before you come back, I'll tell "
                              "them that you are not available. You can add your own afk message!")
async def afk(ctx, message = "Gatau ngapain"):
    global afkdict

    if ctx.message.author in afkdict:
        afkdict.pop(ctx.message.author)
        await ctx.author.edit(nick="")
        await ctx.send('Welkom bek :-)')

    else:
        afkdict[ctx.message.author] = message
        await ctx.author.edit(nick="[AFK]")
        await ctx.send("Siap bang jago")
```